# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll' refer to the same metadata but only one is a linked reference

Tags: c#, package

I am facing this issue, please help me to fix it.

[image]

this package is located in the packages folder of my folder.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly it has something to do with the office installation when you have or had two different versions of office, check the install folder of office and make sure that only one excel interop dll is present

Comment: yep, i fixed it my removing one!